# How to calculate the height of tree based on uneven split of input size?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I'm going through CLRS material on Quicksort and while analyzing average case, the input was split in the ratio of 1:9. And the height of the tree is given as log_10/9 n. A typical binary tree has a max height of log_2 n.  How do I get at log_10/9 n. What does it even mean?

Edit: CLRS 3e Pg 176

Answer (score 0):

If I can remember my math correctly:

```
x=log_10/9(n)
```

means (10/9)^x = n.  Using ln (natural logorithm - base e) we could also use log10

```
x[ln(10/9)] = ln(n)
x = ln(n)/ln(10/9)
```

As a check, if we didn't know how to do log_2(8):

```
x = [ln(8) / ln(2)] = 3 which is correct
```

(I used a scientific calculator for ln(8) and ln(2))